# WireMock stub creation fails: expects 201 but gets 200

Tags: java, unit-testing, wiremock

I am new to WireMock and trying to get my first unit test to work with it. Now, following the docs on wiremock.org, I wrote this

```
    WireMockConfiguration config = wireMockConfig().port(9089).httpsPort(8443);
    m_wireMockServer    =       new WireMockServer(config);

    m_wireMockServer.start();
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 9089);
    givenThat(get(urlEqualTo("/some/thing"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        .withBody("Hello world!")));
```

I expect this to make any http request to /some/thing to be caught. It gives me the following exception on the giventhat call:

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected status 201 for http://localhost:9089/__admin/mappings/new but was 200
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.postJsonAssertOkAndReturnBody(HttpAdminClient.java:151)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:65)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:130)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:126)
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:65)
```

What did I miss? What is wrong in the creation of the stub?

Comment: Let's start with the difference in URLs here.  The URL you have in the `get` method call is different than the URL that's failed the assertion.

Comment: Yes, the test in which I want to use the mocked behaviour of /some/thing is not even started here. I want get requests to /some/thing to behave like defined for my test. But the exception happens with the registering of this behaviour. The registration returns 200, but needs 201 as I understood well.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, that you have Wiremock running in the background all the time between test runs, therefore when you are setting up a new mapping in test, the mapping is not really new as there is already an existing one and Wiremock responds 200(OK) instead of 201(Created).

To test this hypothesis, try to locate process on port assigned to Wiremock, if there is one, kill it and run test again.

Comment: Related to this, I was facing the same issue as the question author, and found that I actually had a service running locally on the same port which I had assigned to WireMock. Shutting down that locally running application fixed the problem for me.